# Dynamically adding panel to other panel in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2

I want to do something like this: when user will click button then on Hbox should shows up my, before designed in .fxml file, panel. On this panel are gonna be some buttons and ListView (and some other things, no matter right now). My question is: how to dynamically add panel into other panel? I mean, how should look class of my panel?

Comment: you can try using multiple screens in javafx. Just follow this link : https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1.

Comment: Just do it... what part are you stuck with? Register an event handler for the button, inside it load the FXML and add the result to the `HBox`. If it doesn't work, post a [MCVE] that shows what you have tried.